# Using AJAX to delete model data - Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a javascript alert (It uses swal to style it, but it functions like a regular alert). I want to run `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()` after the ok button is clicked. I did research online, and I came across many articles talking about using Ajax, but I can't really figure out how to implement it in my  program. Can someone please help me? My JS is down bellow:

```
swal({
  title: "Accept Donation",
  text: "Are you sure you would like to accept the donation titled {{donation.title}}, which was posted on {{donation.date}} by {{donation.user}}?",
    
  icon: "info",
  buttons: true,
  
})
.then((ok) => {
  if (ok) {
    swal("Donation successfully accepted, please contact {{donation.user}} at {{donation.phonenumber}}, for instructions as to when and where you should pick up the donation", {
      icon: "success",
            
    });
  } 
});
}
```

URL:

```
path('donations/<int:pk>/', views.DonationDetail.as_view(), name='donation-detail'),
```

View:

```
class DonationDetail(DetailView):
    model = Donation
    queryset = Donation.objects.all()
    template_name = 'acceptdonation.html'
```

Comment: What did you try where did you fail, I am not seeing any ajax or fetch being used in your code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX can be implemented by using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

A request should be made after the result from clicking the alert has an `ok` truthy value. So after checking if `ok` is good call the `fetch` function with the URL to send the request to **(1)**.

In this example I'm using the `DELETE` method, as it feels appropriate, and send an object with an `id` property as JSON **(2)**. Python doesn't understand JavaScript and vice versa, but both languages understand JSON. This enables you to send data between languages.

**Sidenote: your code does not show any sign of an id, so I just assume that there is one in `donation.id`.**

Your server (Django) should receive any incoming data that is sent to the --in this example-- `/donations` URL. And it should allow the `DELETE` method.

Now the id of the donation to get is inside a JSON string. Decode the body of the request to get access to that id.

The `fetch` function returns a `Promise`, just like `swal` does. This allows you to chain your code and show the second alert whenever the `fetch` request has successfully finished **(3)**.

```
swal({
  title: "Accept Donation",
  text: "Are you sure you would like to accept the donation titled {{donation.title}}, which was posted on {{donation.date}} by {{donation.user}}?",
  icon: "info",
  buttons: true,
})
  .then((ok) => {
    if (ok) {
      // (1) Make a request DELETE to /donations.
      return fetch("/donations", {
        method: "DELETE",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: "{{donation.id}}" // (2) Include the id and send it as JSON.
        })
      });
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // (3) If response is successful, show the second alert.
    if (response.ok) {
      swal("Donation successfully accepted, please contact {{donation.user}} at {{donation.phonenumber}}, for instructions as to when and where you should pick up the donation", {
        icon: "success",
      });
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but your code does not work. I get the following message in my terminal: `Not Found: /donations
[26/Jul/2021 11:47:11] "DELETE /donations HTTP/1.1" 404 3633`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the id

Comment: I will update my question to include my view and url, I think it has something to do with that

Comment: I don't assign an ID to my model, is that something that you would recomend I do?

Comment: Well, to be fair. Your asked how to implement AJAX. This is the client side part. You'll need to create an endpoint in Django to send the request to. An Endpoint is a URL that triggers backend logic and sends a response. You don't have that yet, but you need it. Your question shows that you need an id at 'SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()'. How would you otherwise filter the data?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will mark this question as complete, because it did answer my Ajax question. I need to get it to function, so I asked another question. This is the other question if you want to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533406/django-assigning-id-to-model/68533787?noredirect=1#comment121121133_68533787 ( I am rewarding anyone who helps with cash)