# Django - Assigning Id to model

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am creating a donation like ecommerce site that allows people to donate and sell stuff. I have a screen, called **acceptdonation**, which allows people to see details about a certain donation. I have a button on that screen, which a user can click if they want to accept the donation. When this button is clicked, I display an alert (it uses `swal` to style, but functions like a regular alert), and if the user clicks on the `ok` button, I want to delete that specific data that they are looking at. I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521933/using-ajax-to-delete-model-data-django) question, and I was given an answer that requires me to use an **id**. I don't assign an id in my model, and they way I render out my donation is down bellow. I was wondering how I can assign a unique id to each one of my donations so I can delete them later on. My code is in detail bellow. Also please feel free to ask any questions, I am always on my pc.

Swal alert (I need to assign an id in order for this to work):

```
swal({
  title: "Accept Donation",
  text: "Are you sure you would like to accept the donation titled {{donation.title}}, which was posted on {{donation.date}} by {{donation.user}}?",
  icon: "info",
  buttons: true,
})
  .then((ok) => {
    if (ok) {
      // (1) Make a request DELETE to /donations.
      return fetch("/donations", {
        method: "DELETE",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: "{{donation.id}}" // (2) Include the id and send it as JSON.
        })
      });
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // (3) If response is successful, show the second alert.
    if (response.ok) {
      swal("Donation successfully accepted, please contact {{donation.user}} at {{donation.phonenumber}}, for instructions as to when and where you should pick up the donation", {
        icon: "success",
      });
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Donation Model:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  quantity  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,)
  image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')       
  description = models.TextField()
  date = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=999)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Class based view that allows me to render out the donations:

```
class DonationDetail(DetailView):
    model = Donation
    queryset = Donation.objects.all()
    template_name = 'acceptdonation.html'
```

URL associated with `DonationDetail` (this creates a custom url for every one of my donations)

```
path('donations/<int:pk>/', views.DonationDetail.as_view(), name='donation-detail'),
```

### I have been struggling with this problem for a long time, I am willing to donate $10 to anyone who helps me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `Donation` model almost certainly has an ID. This is because of the default configuration for models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields and the fact it looks like you're already using it via `/donations/<int:pk>/`, the `<int:pk>` parameter is referencing the ID.

Your Javascript looks roughly correct, you are placing `{{donation.id}}` in your body to indicate the donation to be deleted, as suggested in the last question.

**To really answer this, we need to know what does your `DELETE` path look like in Django-land?** If you don't have one, I'd start there.

*BTW the "RESTful" way to do this would be a `DELETE` request ***without*** a body to `/donations/<int:pk>` where `<int:pk>` is the ID of the donation you want to delete. What you have might work too, but conventionally `DELETE` requests don't have bodies.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I don't really understand what you mean. After using the code in the following question, I  the following message in my terminal: `Not Found: /donations [26/Jul/2021 11:47:11] "DELETE /donations HTTP/1.1" 404 3633 `

Comment: "To really answer this, we need to know what does your DELETE path look like in Django-land? If you don't have one, I'd start there."

You need to create a view in Django that handles the `DELETE` request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/#the-view-layer

Comment: Would you be willing to show me how to make the delete view?

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to take that journey yourself. I'm sure it's been answered on StackOverflow before though and the Django documentation is very good.

Comment: Ok. If you ever do change your mind, please feel free to answer. I am offering $10 to anyone who can sucsesfully solve my problem

Comment: @yojoeto to help you get started, have a read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)